# adding UIButton to UITextField causing unrecognized selector sent

Tags: iphone, objective-c, unrecognized-selector

The error I have is:

```
2011-03-12 20:48:33.861 SmarTrek[22040:207] -[RouteViewController selectFavorite]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5b154a0
2011-03-12 20:48:33.863 SmarTrek[22040:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'
```

The code is:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"add.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"add.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    button.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 29);
    button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -24, 0, 0);
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(selectFavorite) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


    UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"add.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"add.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    button1.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 29);
    button1.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -24, 0, 0);
    [button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(selectFavorite) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    origin.rightView = button;
    destination.rightView = button1;
    origin.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
    destination.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;


    self.navigationItem.title = @"Where to go?";
    //self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem;
    //self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem;
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (IBAction) selectFavorite:(id) sender
{
    NSLog(@"TEST");

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The methods referred to by `@selector(selectFavorite)` and `@selector(selectFavorite:)` are not the same, the colon is significant. Since your method is `- (IBAction) selectFavorite:(id) sender`, you need to include the colon in the `@selector`.

Comment: missed that! thanks for pointing that out.. by the way can't I just have one UIButton to be used in two places?

Comment: You might be able to get away with it if the two different places are never "in existence" at the same time, not even when transitioning from one view controller to another. Otherwise you'll run into trouble where the button is missing from where it should be because it has been taken for the other place. It would be better just to create two identical button instances and avoid all that trouble.